# how to get kernel panic message logged?

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader, buildroot

i am trying to build a custom Linux kernel for the Intel nuc board.

first of all i have installed clearlinux(a Linux distribution) on bare metal. Im trying to install the custom Linux alongside the clearlinux by placing the kernel in /efi/boot and the added a entry in /efi/loader/entries . Im using systemd as my default boot loader.

Im getting kernel panic while im trying to boot the custom linux. The problem is i couldn't see the entire message in my console.

is there any way that i could load the message in to a file and view`enter code here` or could add some options to the kernel parameters so that i can navigate through the entire kernel panic text

here is my kernel entry

```
title customoslinux 
linux /EFI/custom/bzImage 
options root=PARTUUID=0de21747-3184-47eb-a415-720247c9abc6 quiet console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 init=/usr/bin/initra-desktop
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/104771/where-are-kernel-panic-logs

Answer (score 0):

You may add "vga=ask" to your kernel commandline and before kernel start it will ask you for screen resolution. Just choose some big resolution and start the kernel.

Comment: that option doesn't seem to work. kernel not seem to recognize that command.

Comment: If you are able to connect serial terminal -  do it - it is the easiest solution. If not - you can recompile the kernel adding vga=ask option.